# Getting the value of the selected cells in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell

I'm using some freebie script to highlight table cell when it's clicked. It can be clicked multiple, so I can have selected many cells in one time. When I'm clicking the cells I want  to retrieving values of them and displaying into input below so I can POST it when I finish highlighting. My script looks like below:

```
function displayVals(item) {
        var multipleValues = $(this).html() || [];
        $("p.info").html("<b>Multiple:</b> " + multipleValues.join(", "));
        alert($(item).html()); 
        $("#clicked").val(multipleValues.join(", "));
    }

    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $('#table3').highlight('td');
            $('#table3').highlight('td', 'highlight-selected', 'mousedown');
            $('#table3 td').click(function() { 
                displayVals(this);
            });

        }
    );
```

In this example in `displayVals` function I'm using `alert` to showing which cell I select now. It's shows with no problem but nothing paste in the input called `clicked` and nothing appear in `p.info`.

If anyone can help me with that I will be grateful.

Comment: oh. and in `displayVars` when i use `item` in mullipleValues define the alert window crash and nothing happen than.

Comment: you already use item in the alert and what does crash mean?

Comment: alert with `item` on it shows on the screen but alert with `item` and `item` in multipleValues stops showing alert eather.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the click event `this` points only to the clicked element not to all tds.

```
$('#table3 td').click(function() { 
     displayVals(this);
});
```

The `.html()` returns a string so you don't need the joins and you use `this` instead of `item`:

```
function displayVals(item) {
    var multipleValues = $(item).html() || '';
    $("p.info").html("<b>Multiple:</b> " + multipleValues);
    alert($(item).html());
    $("#clicked").val(multipleValues);
}
```

List all multiple Values

```
function displayVals(item) {
  var multipleValues = [];
  $(item)
    // Search the parrent table
    .closest('table')
    // Get any highlight selected td
    .find('td.highlight-selected')
    // Iterate and add the html to multipleValues
    .each(function(){ multipleValues.push($(this).html()) })


    $("p.info").html("<b>Multiple:</b> " + multipleValues.join(", "));
    alert(multipleValues.join(", "));
    $("#clicked").val(multipleValues.join(", "));

}
```

Comment: as i say below. when i hit `$(item)` in `multipleValues` there's nothing happend. take a look in the demo http://kam1ll0.vot.pl/hi.php

Comment: yeah, we're close. but i want to multipleValues and now the input values erase upon new value. i want to seperate by comma

Comment: sorry, not working. nothing happens. maybe something else? thank U.

Comment: sorry there is a typo use `each` instead of `foreach`.

Comment: hey Ghommey! i figured it out by myself already. Just in the same time as you wrote answer! Another bug is in the "foreach" line. missing () in `html` tag. Than it works perfecly. Please correct your solution, than i will set it as "correct answer". Many thanks! Cheers

Comment: hi again! i not sure if i can write this here when the main question is answered but i want to make a little modification to this script above. shortly. Now the script is copying value of the table cell to the input. in my mod in the cell i have some img and hidden input with some value. when i click on the cell i want to copy value from the hidden input to the input from the original script. i think it's somewhere in the multipleValues.push() line but i don't know what to  insert into selector. maybe someone will know the aswer for this case. Ghommey R U There ? Cheers

Comment: `$(".mySelector",this)` will return any element within the current td.

Comment: invaluable. everytime i learn something new about jquery. you've got a beer Ghommey! Cheers